# Sitecore 9.0.1 Datepicker displaying wrong format

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, speak, datetimepicker

I'm facing DateTime format issue on the SPEAK DateTime Picker. Basically, when the user is in the Content Editor, the format displays ok (`mm/dd/yyyy`).

But when the user opens the Experience Editor, clicks on the field, and clicks on the calendar icon, and it will show a pop-up. This pop-up (**Select Date**) is showing the wrong date-time format(`dd/mm/yyyy`).

The only solution that I found so far was editing the associated JavaScript file
(`\sitecore\shell\client\Business Component Library\Layouts\Renderings\Common\DatePickers\DateTimePickers.js`).

Does anyone has a more elegant solution for this issue? I already tried things like `DefaultRegionalIsoCode` but it seems it does not affect the SPEAK Component, so far just this change on .js worked

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad that Sitecore is now aware of the bug and it will provide a official fix

I made a blog about this a couple months ago with the detailed Discussion and the research of the issue

https://errorcotidianam.wordpress.com/2018/04/30/sitecore-9-1-datepicker-displaying-wrong-format/

I will also update my blog post with this version provided from Sitecore

Thanks for letting me know that .

Answer (score 2):

According to the help desk, yes you still have to edit the file.

```
\sitecore\shell\client\Business Component Library\Layouts\Renderings\Common\DatePickers\DatePicker.js
```

But instead of fixing the hard-coded date format to your desired format, update this line:

```
this.model.set("dateFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy");
```

To this:

```
this.model.set("dateFormat", this.$el.attr("data-dateformat"));
```

I'm not sure yet if Sitecore considers this a bug and if it will be fixed in future versions (it is there in 90u1 and u2). As soon as they answer this question I will let you know.

Comment: Sitecore responded: "The bug was not yet fixed in a public release, and there is no specific ETA or version number, unfortunately. When the bug is fixed, it's reference number will be added to the appropriate release notes."