# DatePicker displays incorrect format in Experience Editor

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

We have a date field on an item in Sitecore (version 8.1 Update 3). When that field is rendered in the Content Editor, the correct date formatting is used (US, in our case: `MM/DD/YYYY`):

[image: Date picker in Content Editor]

However, when that page is loaded in the Experience Editor, the date picker displays the wrong format (`DD/MM/YYYY`):

[image: Date picker in Experience Editor]

Does anyone know how to make the Experience Editor date picker show the proper format?

I've already reviewed [a similar-looking question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11553/sitecore-9-0-1-datepicker-displaying-wrong-format), but our `DatePicker.js` already had the updated code, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Which Sitecore version you are on Dan ?

Comment: Sorry, Sitecore 8.1u3. (Question updated.)

Comment: I have a case open with sitecore for this same issue in sitecore 8.2u7.  I'll post there solution when I here back from them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore has a [hotfix for this issue](https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.51661/releases) (reference number 51661).

Fixing the issue involves adding the Sitecore Support DLL (`Sitecore.Support.51661.dll`) and making a modification to the SPEAK presentation details of the `SelectDateTime` dialog in the Experience Editor to use the new type from the DLL.

Comment: https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.51661/releases

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore support sent me a link to the following [KB article](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/80/components/datepicker).  So what I ended up doing was modifying the `sitecore\shell\client\Business Component Library\Layouts\Renderings\Common\DatePickers\datepicker.js` file.

In the `view: {....}`which is near the top of the file, add `this.setDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");`

this is what it looks like in my file

```
    view: {
  initialized: function () {
    var days = {
      "Monday": 1,
      "Tuesday": 2,
      "Wednesday": 3,
      "Thursday": 4,
      "Friday": 5,
      "Saturday": 6,
      "Sunday": 7
    };

    this.model.on("change:date", this.setFormattedDateAttribute, this);

    this.model.on("change:formattedDate", this.setDateAttribute, this);

    this.model.set("firstDay", days[this.$el.attr("data-firstday")]);
    this.model.set("showOtherMonths", this.$el.attr("data-showothermonths") === "true");
    this.model.set("showButtonPanel", this.$el.attr("data-showtoday") === "true");
    this.model.set("viewMode", this.$el.data("viewmode"));

    this.model.set("isEnabled", this.model.get("viewMode") != "calendar" ?
      !this.$el.is(":disabled") : this.$el.attr("data-isenabled") === "true");

    if (this.$el.attr("readonly")) {
      this.model.set("isReadOnly", this.$el.attr("readonly"));
    } else {
      $.noop();
    }
     this.model.set("disabled", !this.model.get("isEnabled"));

    this.model.on("change:dateFormat", this.changeDateFormat, this);
    this.model.on("change:isEnabled", $.proxy(changeDisabled, this));

    this.model.set("dateFormat", this.$el.attr("data-dateformat"));

    this.model.set("time", this.$el.attr("data-time"));
    this.model.on("change:time", this.timeUpdated, this);

    this.model.on("change:minDate change:maxDate", this.changeRange, this);
    this.model.set("minDate", this.$el.attr("data-mindate"));
    this.model.set("maxDate", this.$el.attr("data-maxdate"));

    if (this.$el.attr("data-localization")) {
      this.setLocalization();
    }

    this.overWriteSetDateMethod(this.setDate);      
    this.setDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
  },
```

this corrected my issue as shown in the screen shot.

[image: Date picker with valid format]

Comment: If possible, I'd like to avoid hardcoding the format string into the JS. I've got a ticket open with Sitecore Support, too, and I'm hoping for a more comprehensive fix.

Comment: They are supposed to be back to me with the same.  For now, I am using the above as a stop gap solution.

Comment: I found a much more elegant solution and updated my post.

Comment: I agree that this is better, but it's still hardcoding the format, unfortunately. I with it was just setting the right format in `this.model.set("dateFormat", this.$el.attr("data-dateformat"))`

Comment: Yep, me too. I added an answer with that info.